# UIToolbar gets pushed off screen when moving between controllers

Tags: ios, uistoryboard, uitoolbar

Ok so this doesn't seem to be a coding issue as it more has to do with the storyboard/layout. I've searched around stackoverflow and elsewhere for a possible solution but from some of the responses I've seen, this might be a bug with iOS6. Though I'm wondering if anyone else has come across this issue:

Basically, I have a view controller with a nav bar on top and a tool bar on the bottom. Taking  up the entire screen is a UIImage. The issue is that when I go to this view controller, some of the time the toolbar is on the bottom, and some of the time it looks like it's getting pushed off by the UIImage. If I shrink the UIImage slightly so it isn't touching the toolbar it completely resolves the issue, but then this leave a white gap between the toolbar and the UIImage. Has anyone else ever experienced this?

EDIT: I've found a workaround. Basically, I just selected both the UIImage and UIToolbar and pinned their respective heights to keep them constant no matter what. Though, I admit this doesn't really explain the issue I was having.

[image: UIImage in storyboard]

Comment: "some of the time the toolbar is on the bottom, and some of the time it looks like it's getting pushed off by the UIImage" -- what are the circumstances where it works sometimes and not others? Does it appear to be random?

Comment: Yes, it appears to be random. That is, if I hit the back button and then the button to go back to the view controller enough times I can simulate both results.

Comment: I experimented with this, and I can't reproduce your result. I doubt this is a bug or a random thing. If you could post a picture of your storyboard (either here or some sharing site) it would be helpful. Also, you should try experimenting some more to see if a specific set of transitions between views will reliably reproduce the bad effect.

Comment: I found a workaround (added an edit above). Just out of curiosity, when you were experimenting, did you use an image that was bigger than the UIImage frame? Mine are bigger than the frame so they get resized. When I use a smaller image there is no issue. However, this doesn't explain why sometimes the UIImage expands past the toolbar and sometimes it doesn't.

Comment: Yes, the image I was using was bigger than the image view.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by the constraint settings for each element.  Under the size inspector you can adjust those settings.  Basically what you want is the NavBar to be static at the top of the screen, the ToolBar to be static at the bottom of the screen, and the ImageView to stretch between them.[image: imageView constraints]

Another cause could be if you are using -initWithImage because this will adjust the size of the frame to match the size of the specified image.  If an image is several pixels too tall this could push the toolBar off screen.  A solution in this case is to use -initWithFrame on the UIImageView and then set the image property.

Comment: I think you are right about the constraints. How do I change Top Space to navigation bar though? It looks like it's already set bottom space to toolbar which is fine. Currently, top space is set to superview.

Comment: I've been experimenting with constraints but am unable to create a different result. The weird thing about this is is that the UIToolbar works correctly about half the time (not getting pushed off by image) leading me to wonder if this isn't just a massive bug on Apple's part.